# C# Task.WaitAll slow , any alternative

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

i am using c# to data process some calculations  over database table every loop it process about 3000 employee data .
each employee take about 2 second to finish

that mean too much time (2*3000=6000 second/loop)
so we decided to use .net threads but we still face same slow with Task.WaitAll

any ideas , any alternative , how to finish all in same time ? or time faster than this

here is our service code

my algorithm is like this

1. fetch all  new employees actions
2. loop over each employee in parallel (it finish in 2 second if for 1
   employee)

> problem here for many employees it take a long time even with tasks

3. fetch again  new employees actions

   ```
   /// seperate tasks
       List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
       foreach (Helper.Employeedata employee in employees)
       {
           Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               employee.loadActions();
           });

           tasks.Add(t);
       }

       Console.WriteLine("Waiting ...");
       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
   ```

Comment: Are you saying that `Task.WaitAll` is slow, or that the work you do in threads is slow? You do realize that `Task.WaitAll` will wait until the work is done (hence the name)?

Comment: its slow same as not using tasks  , finish in same time , in more than 1 hour per loop , i need to reduce that since each employee take 2 second , but using task has no effect here

Comment: Becareful of that `foreach`, if you are not using Visual Studio 2013 or newer you will get incorrect beavior due to how variable capture in a `foreach` works. The behavior was changed in 2013 and will work fine, but if you are using 2012 or older you will get `employee.loadActions()` called on the same employee multiple times.

Comment: If each employee takes 2 seconds, fix `loadActions`. Show the code for that function and we can help you out. There may be better ways to do it, or optimisations that can be made. Go use the profiler built in to Visual Studio and run the program without tasks, see exactly which line inside `loadActions` is taking the most time and share that here.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it take 2 second to load all his action / notfications  / save to db etc ,  i am looking for a way to process multi employee in same time ,

Comment: @ScottChamberlain and yes i am using VS2015

Comment: You should remove the line `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());`

Comment: @Rahul Its not about blocking operation   - its about the time it take to finish a loop -i need to optimise the time it take per loop , it  take about 1 hour in each refresh

Comment: @Eng-AymanAbdulhamidElarian you have something in `loadActions` that is not letting it run in parallel, without us seeing what it is doing we can't help you. Any other altertive will have the same problem, you have to fix `loadActions` to allow it to be run in parallel. If you are talking to a DB, likely you just need a index on the correct tables, but we can't tell you what index unless you show us what you are doing.

Comment: Example: A person can answer one question in 2 seconds. It does not matter if you ask him 3000 questions or if 3000 people ask him one question. It will take the same time. To reduce time you have to increase the answer giving people.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain any way to trace that it go in parallel  or not ?

Comment: @SirRufo thats why  iam using parallel it must be same as  increase the answer giving people.

Comment: It is is running in parallel, it is just running slowly in parallel. The best option would be make it single again, fix the queries to be faster, then if it still is not fast enough try parallel again. 2 seconds is way too long for a DB call and is a very good sign you are missing a index.

Comment: @Eng-AymanAbdulhamidElarian No, you have only switch from one task asking 3000 questions to 3000 tasks asking one question

Comment: @ScottChamberlain its not select  , select come before this step , in this step we apply some actions based on rows , i will check it more , but the only thing we connect to db in this step is to save rows ,

Comment: And if you are using Entity Framework it is known to be bad a updating rows in bulk like that, there are ways to fix it but FIRST YOU HAVE TO SHOW US HOW YOU ARE SAVING SO WE KNOW WHAT SOLUTIONS TO SUGGEST!

Comment: @SirRufo hmmm so how we solve this ?

Comment: @Eng-AymanAbdulhamidElarian We can not look into your computer or in your brain - so it is hard to say how to solve this - we don't know what you are really doing in loadActions()

Comment: @ScottChamberlain in this step we use local dataTable to store and after all process done we use SqlBulkCopy to batch insert  to db to make it faster ,  i am trying to share but loadActions is a method that run many extended class methods and actions ,

Comment: i will try to share some code

Comment: Do you use some kind of synchro objects inside the loadActions processing?

Comment: no , each  employee.loadActions have its own objects pass on employee class as employee is a class with data that will be processed

Answer (score 1):

```
Parallel.ForEach(employees, employee => loadAction(employee));
```

If "loadActions" is CPU-intensive, then there is nothing much you can do besides upgrading your computer or rewriting your code.

Comment: If it were only cpu then he would have seen a reduce in time - but it takes the same time if parallel or not. So cpu is not the cause

Comment: cpu is not the cause i have test it on an powerful  server